# JAVA library for SVM-HMM or other sequential based classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, svm, stanford-nlp

Could I find an implementation for SVM classifier based on Hidden Markov Model in JAVA ????

In other words, I'm looking for a JAVA implementation of Sequential based classifier for words with Some features in a sentence.

Any Help ??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) is a good package for sequence tagging. You can use [Mallet-LibSVM](https://github.com/syeedibnfaiz/Mallet-LibSVM) to get Support Vector Machines as well.